# DataGrid one row of checkbox checked should change another row of checkbox visibility using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, datagrid

I've one DataGrid in my page(.aspx) and the code is given below,

Page.aspx

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="myDataGrid" runat="server" AutoGeneratedColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanged="myDataGrid_Page"  OnItemDataBound="myDataGrid_ItemDataBound">

<Columns>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="SlNo" Visible="False">
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="_lblID" Text='<% DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>' runat="server"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Select">
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="_chkSelect" runat="server"/> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateColumn>
.... 
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Page.aspx.cs

```
protected void myDataGrid_Page(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
   myDataGrid.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   _BindDataGrid();
}

protected void myDataGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header && e.Item.ItemType !=     ListItemType.Footer)
  {
   Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("_lblID") as Label;
   CheckBox chk = e.Item.FindControl("_chkSelect") as CheckBox;
   chk.Checked = lbl.Text.ToLower() == "2";
  }
}
```

UI

```
---------------------------------------
Select
---------------------------------------
#
#
#(checked)
#
#
---------------------------------------
```

If i check 5th checkbox, needs to disable 4th checkbox in the datagrid and 
If i uncheck 5th checkbox, needs to enable 4th checkbox in the datagrid. 
Can anyone please suggest how to do it?

Comment: You can do it client side or server side. Client side your checkbox have different name and you can add other data attributes as `<asp:CheckBox ID="_chkID" data-number='<%# "chk" + Container.ItemIndex %>' runat="server"/>`. then you can use jquery to edit checked property. 

Or server side you can use AutoPostBack="true" and change the checked property OnPreRender (it depends from conditions). 

You can also use Imagebutton (using two images for checkbox checked or not checked) instead of Checkbox and work OnItemCommand event.

Comment: I think you miss a # in Label control databinding in your post: <%#

Comment: Deleted my answer actually didn't notice it a datagrid.